# Can attacks be adjusted to fit the Artificer's mechanical servant's form?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, unearthed-arcana, artificer

I am planning to DM a game and I have a person wanting to be an artificer.

I was curious if the player could adjust attacks to fit the form of their mechanical servant? [The following is stated in the UA](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/1_UA_Artificer_20170109.pdf):

> Select    a   Large beast with    a   challenge   rating  of
>   2 or  less.   The servant uses    that beast’s    game
>   statistics,   but it  can look    however you like,   as long as  its form    is  appropriate for its statistics.

So, could he for example use the statistics from the giant elk, but change the 'Hooves' attack, which is only allowed to be used on prone targets, to work on standing targets, if he describes the form to be a like a humanoid giant which he can ride?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### You're better off having him choose a different creature

As GM it's always at your discretion that you can houserule such things, but generally it's a no. As your quote states, you take the stats as they are written.

There's also a small issue with your example of the creature your player likely desired.  A *Giant Elk* is **Huge**, that's one whole size above **Large**. The stats of a [Giant Boar](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Giant%20Boar#content) would be a decent fit for your player's needs.

Should you want to browse all possible creatures that could be used as a base for the servant, I recommend you use [Kobold Fight Club's](https://kobold.club/fight/) extensive listing of creatures and where you can find their stats. You can filter for size, max/min CR as well as the source books/sites on there, so you can also explicitly search for SRD stuff that is available for free online.

Answer (score 15):

Generally speaking, no, because the feature says:

> it can look however you like, as long as its form is appropriate for its statistics

And whenever you feel the need to change statistics (or attacks) to fit the form, that's a clear sign you picked something that isn't appropriate for the chosen statistics.

Answer (score 7):

**No**

As you quoted: The servant uses that beast’s game
statistics

Changing the attack is changing the statistics, and so not allowed by RAW.

As it also says, you can change the appearance but only in a way that is still suitable for those existing statistics.